# Group data by leading portion of keys and push values into each group as indexed elements

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, substring, grouping

I have the following working code that from 2 separate arrays ($I & $f) creates  final multidimension array with the data as associated columns.

The problem is i feel the code is clunky, but i cant see if, or how it could me improved. So I'm hoping a second pair of eyes can help.

```
<?php
//main array of input data
$i = [  'input_tickettype1_storeno_00' => null,
        'input_tickettype1_deliverydate_00' => null,
        'input_tickettype1_ticketref_00' => null,
        'input_tickettype1_storeno_01' => '9874',
        'input_tickettype1_deliverydate_01' => '2022-02-01',
        'input_tickettype1_ticketref_01' => 'EDN6547',
        'input_tickettype1_storeno_02' => '8547',
        'input_tickettype1_deliverydate_02' => '2022-01-31',
        'input_tickettype1_ticketref_02' => 'EDN5473',
        'input_tickettype1_storeno_03' => '9214',
        'input_tickettype1_deliverydate_03' => '2022-02-28',
        'input_tickettype1_ticketref_03' => 'EDN1073'
    ];  
//headers
$h = [  'input_tickettype1_storeno' ,
        'input_tickettype1_deliverydate',
        'input_tickettype1_ticketref'
    ];
//final multidim array
$f = array();

//Create a multidim for the headers and the values
foreach ($h as $k => $v)
{
    $f[] = [$v=>null];
}

//loop throught the headers looping for matches in the input data
for ($x = 0; $x < count($f); $x++) {
    foreach ($f[$x] as $fk => $fv) {
        foreach ($i as $ik => $iv) {
            if  (str_contains($ik,$fk)) {
                array_push($f[$x],$iv);
            } 
        }
    }
}
print_r($f);

//Actual Working Output
// Array ( 
//  [0] => Array ( [input_tickettype1_storeno] => 
//                  [0] => 
//                  [1] => 9874 
//                  [2] => 8547 
//                  [3] => 9214 
//              ) 
//  [1] => Array ( [input_tickettype1_deliverydate] => 
//                  [0] => 
//                  [1] => 2022-02-01 
//                  [2] => 2022-01-31 
//                  [3] => 2022-02-28 
//              ) 
//  [2] => Array ( [input_tickettype1_ticketref] => 
//                  [0] => 
//                  [1] => EDN6547 
//                  [2] => EDN5473 
//                  [3] => EDN1073 
//              )
//  )
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed I think the code can be optimised for readability and logic.

I can think of two methods you can use.

### Method 1 : nested foreach

First of all, you don't need a `foreach` to initialize your multidimentional array, you can do it within the main `loop` you use to read the data. So you can remove the `foreach -- $f[] = [$v=>null];`

Then, instead of having 1 `for` and 2 `foreach` you can just have 2 `foreach` one for each array and use a very fast `strpos` to identify if the key matches and populate the final array.

Here's the resulting code.

```php
$f = [];
foreach ($h as $prefix) {
    $f[$prefix] = [];
    foreach ($i as $key => $val) {
        if (strpos($key, $prefix) === 0) {
            $f[$prefix][] = $val;
        }
    }
}
```

This first method is simple, with a straightforward logic. However it requires a nested foreach. Which means that if both arrays get larger, your code gets much slower.

### Method 2 : key manipulation

This method assumes that the keys of the first array never change structure and they are always `somestringid_[digits]`

In this case we can avoid looping the second array and just use a regular expression to recreate the key.

```php
$f = [];
foreach ($i as $key => $value) {
    preg_match('/^(.*)_[0-9]+$/', $key, $m);
    $key = $m[1];
    if (empty($f[$m[1]])) {
        $f[$m[1]] = [];
    }
    $f[$m[1]][] = $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any need to implement any additional data or conditions.  You only need to read your main array, mutate the keys (trim the trailing unique identifiers) as you iterate, and push data into their relative groups.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uSvtj))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $result[preg_replace('/_\d+$/', '', $k)][] = $v;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'input_tickettype1_storeno' => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => '9874',
    2 => '8547',
    3 => '9214',
  ),
  'input_tickettype1_deliverydate' => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => '2022-02-01',
    2 => '2022-01-31',
    3 => '2022-02-28',
  ),
  'input_tickettype1_ticketref' => 
  array (
    0 => NULL,
    1 => 'EDN6547',
    2 => 'EDN5473',
    3 => 'EDN1073',
  ),
)
```